# Spring and Struts 2 integration

Tags: spring, struts2

This is a design level question and i need opinion on what would be a better approach.

The application i am working on uses Struts 2 and Spring (for dependency injection).
Each Action class make a call to Service Layer to perform business functions. All data is saved in Model classes. Every action uses modals to save/edit data. These Modal classes are defined as private members of the class with getter/setters.

Question 1) Should we define the Modal classes as Beans in application context? Currently i have not. On form submit the Struts itself creates the instance. On edit ( when i want to show data on screen ) I have to explicitly create the modal ( using new ). What would be the better approach.

Question 2) Should the beans for Action Classes in aplCntx be defined as scope="prototype" ? Does Struts its self not take care to create new instance of action classes?

Comment: Extra model class is really unnecessary. Because action fits in a model role in MVC.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1:
As Jigar said you don't need to define your action fields as beans in your application context, because most of the time they just carry data between the page and your application, so most probably you either has created them from you service layers and just want to pass them to page for presentation or their data is submitted from the page in which case struts2 takes care of the instantiation.

Question 2:
There's a object factory in struts2 which by default takes care of action creation. You can change this and specify spring to take care of the action creation. First you have to add [spring plugin for struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/spring-plugin.html) to your classpath then add this line to you struts2 config file:

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory"/>
```

Then you create beans for your actions like:

```
<bean id="myActionBean" class="com.my.myAction" scope="prototype">
    ... required properties ...
</bean>
```

Remember you have to set the scope to prototype that's how it works for struts2. Then in your struts config file:

```
<action name="myaAction" class="myActionBean">
    ... required result mapping ...
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Should we define the Modal classes as Beans in application context? Currently i have not. On form submit the Struts itself creates the instance. On edit ( when i want to show data on screen ) I have to explicitly create the modal ( using new ). What would be the better approach.

No. You shouldn't define modal in spring-context , they should be just simple POJOs

Comment: You mean we should not define modals in application-context, rather create a new instance whenever we want one. Is this correct?